# Geometry Nodes: Delete random Vertices on an Edge, except 1

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to get only 1 random vertex on an edge, but my problem is, I don't know how to separate the edges to solve this. My first thought was to delete random vertices except 1.

This is my node setup:

[image: GeometryNodes]

Input mesh are connected edges:

[image]

Viewer output:

[image]

The node setup to get only one random vertex **per** edge should be between the *Delete Geometry* and *Curve to Points* nodes.

I hope you have some good advice for me :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve? I failed to understand it. Every edge (the technical "edge" in Blender) consist of EXACTLY 2 vertices. So it would be less confusing to write "How to delete one vertex from each edge" rather than "randomly except one" - unless you mean something different, but again, I failed to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

I missunterstood the Term "Edge" and was meant "Spline". Sorry for that confusion, thats my fault. So I found a solution with the *Spline Length* node, where I use the *Point Count* socket.

The node setup:

[image]

The whole project is a pipe generator, which generates pipes along edges:

[image]

And I was looking for a node setup where I can instance some things like a valve.
So my goal was to get randomly a point per each spline, just for the first iteration.